# Associate a word and a time with Apache Lucene

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I'm recently using apache Lucene with Java. I have a lot of text documents that I need to index. Each word of each document has a time formatted text associated. My problem is when I make a search with Lucene, I would like to get besides the document score, the time associated with each encountered word. How could I do that?

For example:

Text: "Lucene is a great tool"

Time Associated: "00:00:02 00:00:10 00:01:02 00:01:12 01:00:02"

When I search the words "great tool", I would like to get, besides the score, something like: "00:01:12 01:00:02".

Thank you!

Comment: have a look at https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/PayloadAttribute.html